# Updating multiple fields for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have roughly 600 records that I need to update four fields on each record.  I have the data in excel.  I know I can do a case statement for each field like so

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 =
    CASE
        WHEN id = '123' THEN '2012-01-01'
        WHEN id = '234' THEN '2012-07-01'
            ... and so on...
    END
WHERE id IN ('123','234', ...and so on...)
```

But that would take too long, writing each case (4 times) for each field and row.  Also too much room for error.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary table, insert the data into it, and then use that temp table in an update from select, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (id ..., field1 ..., ....)
INSERT INTO #TempTable (id, field1, field2, ...) VALUES ....

UPDATE
    t
SET
    t.field1 = tmp.field1 
,   t.field2 = tmp.field3
FROM
    MyTable t
JOIN #TempTable tmp ON tmp.Id=t.id
```

You can use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to speed up loading the data into the `#TempTable` faster.

Answer (score 1):

Import the data to a staging table, and then join the target table and the staging table in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    Field1 = S.Field1,
    Field2 = S.Field2,
    ...
FROM
    TargetTable As T
    INNER JOIN StagingTable As S
    ON T.ID = S.ID
```